# Remove background (ghost photo) from an image with characters?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, ocr

I am trying to do text extraction from some images, however, these come with a bit of background, I have tried to "play" with contrast and brightness, as well as looking to apply thresholding techniques like otsu.

Do you have any suggestions on how to improve the extraction? I leave below some parts of the processing, as well as the input and output, any recommendation will be welcome.

Input:
[image: Input]

Output:

[image: output]

Processing:

```
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Brightness(img)
img = enhancer.enhance(1.62)  # 1.8
enhancer2 = ImageEnhance.Contrast(img)
img = enhancer2.enhance(1.8)  # 2
img = np.array(img)
thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

Comment: The text pixels seem to be darker than the background. Try adjusting the threshold value

Comment: I have tried different values with no good results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should perform adaptive threshold. The algorithm divides the image into blocks of pre-defined size. Every block is given a different threshold value based on the pixel intensities within that block. In the following example, threshold is obtained based on Gaussian weight applied to sum of all pixel values within each block (meaning similar pixel values are given more weightage based on Gaussian curve). Binarization is carried out based on this value for each block. Check [this page for more](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)

For the given image, I tried the following:

```
im = cv2.imread('text_block.jpg')
green_channel = im[:,:,1]
th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(green_channel, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 27, 6)
```

[image]

You will have to try tweaking the parameters to get a better result. And also try `cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C`

Comment: looks great, I will try it, is there a reason why you used the green channel to do the processing?

Comment: @isaac.af95 No reason in particular. All the channels appear the same. I wanted to work on a single channel image